# How would I go about avoiding the java.util.ConcurrentModificationException error in the following snippet?

Tags: java

I am attempting to sort student scores from greatest to least and plan to accomplish this by iterating through each item in a HashMap that contains the student name and score, outputting the greatest one, then removing it from the HashMap and repeating until there are no scores left. I understand why I'm getting the ConcurrentModificationException, but am wondering if there is an easy way around it.

```
   // calculates, formats, and outputs scores
   public static void sort (final HashMap<String, Integer> students) {
      for (String i : students.keySet()) {
         System.out.println("key: " + i + " value: " + students.get(i));
      }

      for (String i : students.keySet()) {
         final String key = Collections.max(students.entrySet(),
               Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).getKey();

         System.out.println(key + " " + students.get(key));
         
         students.remove(key);
      }
   }
```

Comment: Alternatively, use a stream - `map.entrySet().stream().sorted(yourComparatorHere).forEach(entry -> print it in desired format)`. No need to modify and make it more complicated.

Comment: I would be very confused if I passed a map into a method called `sort` and my map came back empty after the call!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why modify the map at all? Sort the entries by value, then output the data

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  sort(Map.of("mary", 4, "jane", 2, ".", 0));
}

public static void sort(final Map<String, Integer> students) {
  for (final Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : students.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("key: " + entry.getKey() + " value: " + entry.getValue());
  }

  students.entrySet()
      .stream()
      .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
      .forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue()));
}
```

This will also ensure that an efficient sorting algorithm is used.

Answer (score 0):

I used a stream to resolve the issue as suggested by Chaosfire in the comments.

```
students.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed()) 
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```